# Cookies disappear after reload the page

Tags: javascript, django, cookies

```
response.set_cookie(key=SIMPLE_JWT.get('REFRESH_AUTH_COOKIE'), value=response.data.get('refresh'),
            expires=datetime.now()+SIMPLE_JWT.get('REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME'), samesite='None',
            secure=SIMPLE_JWT.get('AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE'), httponly=SIMPLE_JWT.get('AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY'))
```

I'am using Django Rest Framework to set the JWT Refresh cookie, until this point everything is ok, but when I reload the page the cookie just disappear so I can't retrieve the value any more by JS, but when I send a new request the cookie appears in the Django log. So, I don't know what is happening because the cookie is set in the browser, but in a way that I can't retrieve

Comment: Is httponly set to true?  If so then you will not be able to access the cookie with Javascript.

Comment: no, because of that I think this situation so strange

Comment: i'm using react to frontend so i configure the cookie to be secure=True and samesite='None' to enable cors, do I need to configure anything else?